# CSS file on FTP and in browser are different

Tags: css, ssh, ftp, sftp

I'm really confused as to why my browser is not updating my CSS? I've viewed it on other computers/browsers and cleared the cache but the CSS doesn't seem to update in the browser even if it is already updated via FTP.

Here's the link to the github environment that displays correctly:

https://melvinalvarez.github.io/archive2.0/

Here's the link to the url where it doesn't show the changes:

https://www.melvinalvarez.com/

the "image.css" file is not updating in the browser even if it looks updated in the FTP?

What could be the problem? I updated the files together with my index.html but the css files are the ones that does not seem to update.

I attached screenshots of the difference in the css file that does not seem update on the browser. This is what displays via FTP (I use Forklift which I think is similar to FileZilla)

[image-one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBOOY.png)

and then here is what the browser displays (the css code that links the image to the blank div is missing)

[image-two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCry8.png)

Hope you can help!

Comment: I see the images on `css/images.css` are not the same. Are you using FileZilla Client?

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Remember we don't get paid. Make it easy for us to help you. :) 

What is it supposed to look like and what does it look like? Your CSS files don't have version numbers or anything for us to easily tell them apart. Don't make us look line by line to see what the difference is.

Also, I assume you have tried this in a different browser, on a different system, cleared cache or did something to ensure that your css file isn't just cached locally?

Comment: Yes, I used something similar to FileZilla called Forklift. It usually works fine until I encountered this problem. I checked the WebFTP files on my provider and it did update, it's just when I access the site in the browser, it doesn't display the new code.

Comment: Also, sorry I don't know what css version numbers are and I thought my question was more of an FTP problem and not a code problem so I didn't include it in my question. as mentioned above, I did try it in a different browser, cleared the cache, and checked my providers webFTP to make sure the file was uploaded/updated and it was. It's just weird how it continues to display the old version and that's where I'm stuck

Comment: Can you add 'style.css?dat'e'  then check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this was a CloudFlare issue and purging their cache would solve the css mismatch. Hope this helps anyone encountering the same problem.